# How to Open External link in ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework

Anyone have a idea about how to open external link(outside from my ionic app) in my ionic app. when i tab on the link it will show my app if exsist in mobile.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For opening a link with your app, you can use the `custom-url-scheme` cordova plugin  . This enables you to open your app with an external link like `testapp://path?foo=bar` . Here is the link https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme

Comment: i am also follow this but in this I'm not able to create the schema for my app. like myApp://

Answer (score 12):

Install InAppBrowser:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

npm install --save @ionic-native/in-app-browser
```

Call your links like this:

```
window.open(url, '_system');
```

Answer (score 7):

As described here https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/:

Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/in-app-browser
```

Usage

```
constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) { }
const browser = this.iab.create('https://ionicframework.com/');
// browser.show(), browser.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins: Browser Tab.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-browsertab
npm install --save @ionic-native/browser-tab
```

and

```
import { BrowserTab } from '@ionic-native/browser-tab';

constructor(private browserTab: BrowserTab) {

  browserTab.isAvailable()
  .then(isAvailable => {
  if (isAvailable) {
    browserTab.openUrl('https://ionic.io');
  } else {
    // open URL with InAppBrowser instead or SafariViewController
  }
 });
}
```

[look here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/browser-tab)

Answer (score -2):

Install in App browser .

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Use window.open for this

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/', '_system', 'location=yes');" >Google</a>
```

Refer this link http://intown.biz/2014/03/30/cordova-ionic-links-in-browser/

Comment: hi Anuj, with this we can surely open link that we are share on social sharing app too.

Comment: I didn't get you .

Comment: you see the example image that I'm posted in blog. this is a whats-app page . i open this link on my ionic application . with your reference can i do that?

Comment: ok so you want that if you click on link on whatsapp then it should display open with your app option ?