# How to load external url in ionic div without iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, html, ionic3

I am working in ionic 3.9 mobile app.
I want display website url in ionic div without iframe.
Because ifrmae give error security "X-Frame-Options".
Basic knowledge of inappbrowser and thinable browser but I want add external url in small div not full page.

Comment: probably this may help you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010909/how-to-open-external-link-in-ionic-app

Comment: why not simply use `window.open(url)`

Answer (score 1):

Websites like twitter and instagram already have ready made APIs for embedded views. Maybe try investigating how those are implemented, if you get a security warning maybe the website does not allow it, for instance **[Twitter Widgets](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/timelines/overview.html)**